# persisting database connection parameters in java webapps

Tags: java, web-applications, configuration, persistence

Java webapps provide a convenient way to make them run: It’s suficcient to drop the jar file into tomcat‘s webapps folder or upload it using the tomcat manager. If the jar file is named foo123.jar, the web application is soon accessible under http://<host>:8080/foo123/. However, in the majority of cases, there is a problem with the configuration: It’s a good practice to store data in a database, but where can I store the database connection parameters? Usually you have to adapt some server.xml or web.xml or other configuration file to put it there, but this hinders making use of the automatic deployment for such an application.

A “simple to use” web application should request its required configuration on the first run, like a “setup” screen, and then keep it in some place where it survives a restart of the servlet container. Of course, for database connection parameters, storing them in the database is not an option.

Following the specs, the servlet container has to provide a directory that a web application has write access to. It can be determined using:

```
File tempDir =
(File) session.getServletContext().getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir");
```

The content of this directory is bound to the ‘servlet context lifecycle’, if I got it right this means it is empty after a server restart. If that is true, it cannot be used for my purpose.

Does anybody know some kind of best practice for that? I don’t want to reinvent the wheel.

In lack of a better solution, I would implement it this way: As I said, if you make use of the easy deployment means described above, the context path is derived from the jar file name. So I could imagine to make use of this for the database connection as well. In simple terms: If the web application foo123 finds a MySQL connection on localhost:3306 (the MySQL default port) and can connect to it with username foo123 and password foo123 and has permissions to access a schema called foo123 it always uses that on restart.

What do you think of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use a [context.xml](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html) file. That will let you store the config files on a server-by-server basis and that means that you'll never have to put that information in the code itself.

[This example](http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/Context.xml) seems to sum it up rather nicely.

Comment: It is said [here](http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/Context.xml) that "Tomcat 5.5 and Tomcat 6 copy the context.xml file to <CATALINA>/conf/Standalone after the first the successful deployment, and do not remove or update the file unless the application is undeployed." So the directory **must be writable** to Tomcat and hence to the web app. Remaining questions are, if other web containers (Glassfish, other Tomcat versions) do this, too; how to figure out the location of that “Standalone” dir; and if this works even if the container is told not to unpack the war files to disk.